# How to draw this circuit diagram using tikz

Tags: circuitikz

I want to draw the circuit diagram like this:

[image]

However using my code below, I only able to draw like this:
[image]

```
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
    (opamp.-) to[R=$R_1$] (-4, 0.5){}
    (opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.5) 
    to[R=$R_2$] (1.5,2)
    to[C=$C$] (2,2) -- (2,0)
    %to[C=$C$] (leftC -| opamp.out)
    to[short,-*] (opamp.out);
    \end{circuitikz}
```

Please help. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

i try to redraw showed image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[
    node distance=12mm and 3mm
                        ]
\draw   (0,0)   to [R=$R_1$,o-] ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux1)
                to [R=$R_2$,*-] ++ (2,0)
                to [C=$C$]      ++ (2,0) coordinate (aux2)
                to [short,*-o]  ++ (1,0) coordinate (aux3)
                node[op amp, below right=of aux1, anchor=-] (amp) {}
        (aux1)  |- (amp.-)
        (aux2)  |- (amp.out)
        (amp.+) -- ++ (0,-1)             coordinate (aux4)
                to [short,*-o] (0,0 |- aux4)
        (aux4)  to [short, -o] (aux3 |- aux4);
\path   (0,0)  node[below] {$+$} -- node {$V_d$} (0,0 |- aux4)  node[above] {$-$}
        (aux3) node[below] {$+$} -- node {$V_f$} (aux3 |- aux4) node[above] {$-$};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @adam, if above answer help you and if you liked it, you can accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of the answer).